# Installed 20.04.1 on my old Vista machine with Intel G45 graphics, can't increase screen resolution beyond 1024 x 768

Tags: graphics, 20.04, display-resolution

As the title says, with Ubuntu 20.04 on my Advent QC5003, I can't get the screen resolution up to the 1280x960 which the machine had under Windows Vista. Is there any way I can manage to increase the resolution to that, as there is no option under settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this script to startup applications

```
#!/bin/sh
xrandr --newmode vista_res 101.25 1280 1360 1488 1696 960 963 967 996
xrandr --addmode VGA-1 vista_res
xrandr --output VGA-1 --mode vista_res
```

that fixed it